# Python Excel: how to add a number to each cell in an existing excel file and then send the new value back to excel document

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filenames

How to add a number to each cell in an existing Excel file and then send the new value back to excel document in Python?

Here's what I currently have:

```
for infile in glob2.glob("*.xlsx"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    print(file)

Filename=str(file)+'.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(Filename, index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

#Tell it what columns to read from each file
vals41 = (df['IN/OUT4_1'])
vals41 =(df['IN/OUT4_2'])
vals43=(df['IN/OUT4_3'])
```

I want to add 14.7 to each cell in those 3 columns and then send the new value back to the file.

Comment: What have you tried? Why is it not working? We expect you to make an honest attempt before posting here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, you are trying to update values in excel for 3 specific columns. You can try following code:

```
for infile in glob2.glob("*.xlsx"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    print(file)

Filename=str(file)+'.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(Filename, index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

#Tell it what columns to read from each file
cols=['IN/OUT4_1','IN/OUT4_2','IN/OUT4_3'] 
df[cols] = df[cols]+14.7

df.to_excel(r'Path to store the exported excel file\File Name.xlsx', index = False)
```